# OOM Error on JBoss 4.11

Tags: apache, jboss, out-of-memory

We are maintaining an application which uses Jboss as its AS. Recently customer complained about OOM error and he was unable to login. We restarted Jboss and added configurations to collect heapdump.

*Customer's application usage pattern:* Customer opens a page containing 10 charts which are rendered in an inframe. Flex is used for UI. This page refreshes itself every 5 minutes.

*Request Flow:* The application is built in such a way that all the requests go through Apache (Http) proxy server. Every 5 minutes the dashboard request has to pass through Apache proxy server.

After 5 days OOM error occurred and on analyzing the heapdump we noticed that the error was due to **"org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession", loaded by "org.jboss.mx.loading.UnifiedClassLoader3 @ 0x7b440dd70" occupy 1,776,569,336 (87.71%) bytes.**

**Full description is:**
847,599 instances of "org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession", loaded by "org.jboss.mx.loading.UnifiedClassLoader3 @ 0x7b440dd70" occupy 1,776,569,336 (87.71%) bytes. These instances are referenced from one instance of "org.apache.catalina.Session[]", loaded by "org.jboss.mx.loading.UnifiedClassLoader3 @ 0x7b440dd70"

**Keywords**

```
org.jboss.mx.loading.UnifiedClassLoader3 @ 0x7b440dd70
org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession
org.apache.catalina.Session[]
```

**Common Path To the Accumulation Point says:**

```
java.lang.Thread @ 0x7b4a5f358 ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[jboss.web]] 
org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession @ 0x797b49b70
```

I am new to Jboss and proxy servers. How to debug this issue? Could you please help me.

Thanks
M

Answer (score 0):

org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession is a class representing user http session. I would say, that your every request creates new http session on JBoss which is never expired. Either pass session cookie back to JBoss with every refresh to reuse sessions and not to create new ones. Or configure sensible http session expiration policy in you JBoss.

Good luck,
[Plumbr team](http://plumbr.eu)

Comment: Hi. We are not creating session for every request. When user login to the application session is created. Later for every refresh application just checks if user has logged in or not before processing the request. During first time login a sessiontoken is created and it is placed in map. Thats all.

Comment: Your own data says otherwise: 847,599 instances of "org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession",